# Mongodb $graphLookup build hierarchy

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, graphlookup

I have an output from mongodb `$graphLookup` aggregation:

```
db.getCollection('projects').aggregate([
    {
    $lookup: {
      from: "projects",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "parent",
       as: "childrens"
     }
 }
])
```

---

```
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "name" : "Project1",
    "parent" : null,
    "childrens" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "3",
            "name" : "ProjectForId1",
            "parent" : "1"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : "3",
    "name" : "ProjectForId1",
    "parent" : "1",
    "childrens" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "6",
            "name" : "ProjectForId3",
            "parent" : "3"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "7",
            "name" : "ProjectForId3",
            "parent" : "3"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to build hierarchy from this output in javascript or if is possible directly from query so the final output should look like:

```
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "name" : "Project1",
    "parent" : null,
    "childrens" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "3",
            "name" : "ProjectForId1",
            "parent" : "1",
            "childrens" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : "6",
                    "name" : "ProjectForId3",
                    "parent" : "3"
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : "7",
                    "name" : "ProjectForId3",
                    "parent" : "3"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Also if someone have a brave heart to help in one more case where the hierarchy will be created by filtering _id:

ex: For `_id = "1"` the output will be same as above but if `_id` is `3` the final output should look like:

```
{
    "_id" : "3",
    "name" : "ProjectForId1",
    "parent" : "1",
    "childrens" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "6",
            "name" : "ProjectForId3",
            "parent" : "3"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "7",
            "name" : "ProjectForId3",
            "parent" : "3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Below solution is more or less the same as one of my past answers so you can get thorough explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52662426/6238977)

```
db.projects.aggregate([
    {
        $graphLookup: {
            from: "projects",
            startWith: "$_id",
            connectFromField: "_id",
            connectToField: "parent",
            as: "children",
            maxDepth: 4,
            depthField: "level"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$children"
    },
    {
        $sort: { "children.level": -1 }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            children: { $push: "$children" }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            children: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: "$children",
                    initialValue: {
                        currentLevel: -1,
                        currentLevelProjects: [],
                        previousLevelProjects: []
                    },
                    in: {
                        $let: {
                            vars: {
                                prev: { 
                                    $cond: [ 
                                        { $eq: [ "$$value.currentLevel", "$$this.level" ] }, 
                                        "$$value.previousLevelProjects", 
                                        "$$value.currentLevelProjects" 
                                    ] 
                                },
                                current: { 
                                    $cond: [ 
                                        { $eq: [ "$$value.currentLevel", "$$this.level" ] }, 
                                        "$$value.currentLevelProjects", 
                                        [] 
                                    ] 
                                }
                            },
                            in: {
                                currentLevel: "$$this.level",
                                previousLevelProjects: "$$prev",
                                currentLevelProjects: {
                                    $concatArrays: [
                                        "$$current", 
                                        [
                                            { $mergeObjects: [ 
                                                "$$this", 
                                                { children: { $filter: { input: "$$prev", as: "e", cond: { $eq: [ "$$e.parent", "$$this._id"  ] } } } } 
                                            ] }
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: { children: "$children.currentLevelProjects" }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            _id: "1"
        }
    }
])
```

Last stage is supposed to be the filtering so you can get the data for any level of depth here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately the result that you expected is not ok. 
The ouput is 
`{
    "_id" : "1",
    "name" : "Project1",
    "parent" : null,
    "childrens" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "3",
            "name" : "ProjectForId1",
            "parent" : "1"
        }
    ]
}`

As you can see _id's "6" and "7" are not displayed as childrens for "3"

Comment: @durduliu2009 I assumed that JSON you posted is an input, probably you need to put your lookup in front of it

Comment: @mikl please find my explanation above as comment to my post because here platform tells me that I exceeed with 407 characters... thank you

Comment: @durduliu2009 this changes a lot as you pasted your source data. Fortunately it's very similar to one of my previous answers so you can check my modified post.

Comment: @mikl first of all I want to thank you for your help, i'm really thankfull for your last answer but unfortunately there is still a little problem for this aggregation ... I've updated my comment to question with a new document with _id = 8 and parent = 6 and there seems that this new document "_id": 8 appear in "_id" 6 and 7 but it should be only in "_id" = 6. So the new fully example is updated above. 
Thank you again for your efforts and if for this last problem you can help me I will be really happy

Comment: @mikl new update: I solved it by replacing `[ "$$e.managerId", "$$this.empId"  ]` with `[ "$$e.parent", "$$this._id"  ]` from "mergeObjects" 

Thank you for this great help

Comment: @durduliu2009 sorry for that, just a mistake when copy-pasting, accepted your edit, you can remove your second answer

Comment: thanks for the sorting by depthLevel, it was the most confusing part for me to get from the documentation explanation.

Comment: Very impressive answer @durduliu2009. thanks