# Mongoose $aggregation and $lookup till nth child in the same collection for parent-child relation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a collection called `customers` with the details as similar to below.

```
[
    {accountCode: "1", parentId: "1", accountName: "John Doe" },
    {accountCode: "1.1", parentId: "1", accountName: "John Doe" },
    {accountCode: "1.1.1", parentId: "1.1", accountName: "John Doe" },
    {accountCode: "2", parentId: "2", accountName: "John Doe" },
    {accountCode: "2.1", parentId: "2", accountName: "John Doe" },
    {accountCode: "2.1.1", parentId: "2.1", accountName: "John Doe" },
    {accountCode: "2.1.1.1", parentId: "2.1.1", accountName: "John Doe" },
    {accountCode: "3", parentId: "3", accountName: "John Doe" },
    {accountCode: "3.2", parentId: "3", accountName: "John Doe" },
    {accountCode: "3.2.1", parentId: "3.2", accountName: "John Doe" },
    {accountCode: "3.2.2", parentId: "3.2", accountName: "John Doe" },
    {accountCode: "3.2.3", parentId: "3.2", accountName: "John Doe" },
    {accountCode: "3.2.3.1", parentId: "3.2.3", accountName: "John Doe" }
]
```

all the accounts are inherited by its `accountCode`. I have upto 4 levels at this moment (every levels seperated by `.`, it may grow as per the requirement.
I was trying to aggregate the data as below

```
[
    {
        accountCode: 1, children:[{
            accountCode: 1.1, children: [{
                accountCode: 1.1.1, children: []
            }]
        }]
    },
    {
        accountCode: 2, children:[{
            accountCode: 2.1, children: [{
                accountCode: 2.1.1, children: [{
                    accountCode: 2.1.1.1, children: []
                }]
            }]
        }]
    },
    {
        accountCode: 3, children:[{
            accountCode: 3.2, children: [
                { accountCode: 3.2.1, children: [] },
                { accountCode: 3.2.2, children: [] },
                { accountCode: 3.2.3, children: [
                    { accountCode: 3.2.3.1, children: [] }
                ] }
            ]
        }]
    }
]
```

I'm kind of new to `aggregation` using `mongoose`, and grouping of the data using the aggregation. Hopw do I create this kind of tree? I googled and tried many answeres from stackoverlow and some of them are: [Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61009278/how-to-get-parent-and-parents-siblings-in-a-mongodb-request), [Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50767930/mongodb-graphlookup-get-children-all-levels-deep-nested-result), etc.. but couldnt understand since the requirement is kind of different compared to my requirement. In my case, all the data is in single collection. I tried using `$graphLookup` as well.

Kindly help me with creating an aggregation query.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make node tree with recursive table with Express and Mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65139097/make-node-tree-with-recursive-table-with-express-and-mongo)

Comment: the difference is the key name and needs to put a match stage, look at working [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dWcmrpI5Jun).